# Mobile nav will not collapse on Single-page site using anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation, single-page-application

I'm not sure how to get the mobile navigation that is currently sliding out onto the page to collapse once an anchor link has been clicked from the menu. Currently, the menu just stays open, obscuring the content underneath until the user clicks the "X" button.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-nav-button">
   <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
   <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
   <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
</div>

<nav class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="../img/kct_logo.png"></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#history">HISTORY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
    <li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.mobile-nav-button {
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(2) {
margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line--1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line--2 {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line--3 {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  right: -100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #091525;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mobile-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  background: #835a43; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a:hover:after {
  right: 0;
}

.mobile-menu img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  display: block;
  left: 50%; 
  top: -4rem;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile-menu--open {
 right: 0;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

And finally the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
//Menu button on click event
$('.mobile-nav-button').on('click', function() {
// Toggles a class on the menu button to transform the burger menu into 
a cross
$( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(1)" 
).toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--1");
$( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(2)" 
).toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--2");  
$( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(3)" 
).toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--3");  

// Toggles a class that slides the menu into view on the screen
$('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('mobile-menu--open');
return false;
}); 
});
```

Just wondering if I would need to write some JS that would specifically target any of the anchor links in the menu, and then once any of those are clicked, remove that "mobile-menu--open" class in order to collapse the sliding menu?

Comment: while I write/delete my answer I was looking again and again to your code .. I thought for once its something like conflict on clicks .. **BUT** you've more of classes in js code and just `mobile-menu` in your html code .. please provide the related html/css/js code

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you for your response! I have now edited the original post to include all of the code.

Comment: This is what your code looks like for me in [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xqemchny/) .. please change the code in a fiddle to match your problem .. and you can also take a look at my deleted answer (*if click on any `<a>` the `mobile-menu` will hide*) this is what my answer do .. **OR** if you have a live website you can send the link